# laravel php getting 500 instead of 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

First to start I am newbie in laravel, I am getting a 500 internal server error instead of 404 when going to the wrong page. well after I have freshly installed the framework to my project everything was going well until I have done something I don't know exactly what can it be, this error suddenly started. i went to the error logs of laravel in `storage/logs/laravel.log` and this is what I am getting :

```
[2014-12-06 10:28:29] production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'View [calc/finance/credite] not found.' in /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php:9431
Stack trace:
#0 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(9404): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('calc/finance/cr...', Array)
#1 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(124): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('calc/finance/cr...')
#2 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(3238): Illuminate\View\Factory->make('calc/finance/cr...')
#3 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/app/routes.php(30): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('make', Array)
#4 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/app/routes.php(30): Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::make('calc/finance/cr...')
#5 [internal function]: {closure}('finance', 'credite')
#6 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(5331): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#7 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4998): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4986): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(7746): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#12 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(8353): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#13 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(8300): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#14 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(10962): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /home/jasha/proj/cpcalculateinc/htmlbackup/public_html/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#17 {main} [] []
```

Where should I start looking to solve this problem ?

**UPDATE**:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 minute"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 minute"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.woff$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.ttf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.otf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.svg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.eot$
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is not `404`, but internal error due to exception thrown. THere is `view` missing, so create it or change the route/controller to use another one.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk yes but this is the purpose of 404 error handling, when you type wrong url it should redirect you to the 404 page, instead i am getting 500

Comment: Again, this is not `page not found 404` but exception thrown in your application, ie. `500 internal error`, due to error in the code. Read about error handling, where you can define what happens whenever any exception is thrown (you can show `404` then if you like): http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors

Comment: something is not configured as it should post your htaccess and also check app/start/global.php and see if App::error is configured properly

Comment: @KhanShahrukh I updated it !

Comment: @KhanShahrukh Thanks the problem was in app/start/global.php but I am wondering why is it going to App::Error Instead to App::missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no default 404 page or template, it just throws a standard HTTP exception error page.

The official docs at [Laravel.com](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-404-errors) states the following about 404. Check if your App::missing is configured as it is described

> You may register an error handler that handles all "404 Not Found"
>   errors in your application, allowing you to easily return custom 404
>   error pages:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```